# How do I do the same for character variables?

Tags: sas

My following code gets the job done for numeric variables but not for character variables because proc summary only deals with numeric. The output of the code in the table _final_Alpha gives me the number of missing values only for the numeric variables but I would like it to display that output for the character variables as well. I'm not looking for missing levels data but rather the absolute number of missing values.

The problem is in my proc summary part of the code:

```
proc summary data=&set;
    var _numeric_;
    output out=smry nmiss=;
run;

proc transpose data=smry(drop=_type_ _freq_) out=smry_;
run;
```

Do you know the equivalent code that deals with character variables? My idea is to then get two tables, one dealing with character variables and the other, with numeric. And then, finally, to just append one below the other.

This is what I have with me so far:

```
%macro task_Oct(set);

proc contents data=&set out=con_(rename=(name=tablevar));
run;

proc summary data=&set;
    var _numeric_;
    output out=smry nmiss=;
run;

proc transpose data=smry(drop=_type_ _freq_) out=smry_;
run;

proc sort data=smry_;
    by _name_;
run;

proc freq nlevels data = &set;
ods output nlevels=distinct;
run;

proc sort data=distinct;
    by tablevar;
run;

data final_Alpha (keep=TableVar distinct_ TYPE miss);
    merge distinct(rename=(Nlevels=distinct_)) con_(keep=tablevar type) smry_(rename=(_name_= tablevar col1 = miss));
    by tablevar;
run;

proc sort data=final_Alpha out=_final_Alpha;
by descending miss;
run;

ods select nlevels;
proc freq nlevels data=&set;
tables _all_;
run;

%mend task_Oct;

%task_Oct(sashelp.cars)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this produces the report you are trying to make.

```
%let data=sashelp.heart;

proc transpose data=&data(obs=0) out=names;
   var _all_;
   run;
proc sql;
   select cats('Label _',_name_,'=',quote(_label_),';') into: lb_stmts separated by ' ' from names;
   select cats('_',_name_,'=missing(',_name_,');') into: stmts separated by ' ' from names;
   run;
%put _user_;
data missing;
   set &data;
   &stmts;
   &lb_stmts;
   keep _:;
   run;
ods output summary=summary;
proc means data=missing Sum Mean N STACKODSOUTPUT;
   var _numeric_;
   run;
ods output close;
proc print width=minimum labels;
   label sum='#Missing' mean='%Missing';
   format sum 8. mean percentn8.1;
   run;
```

[image]

Use PROC SQL to generate assignment statements for each variable using MISSING function.

```
%let data=sashelp.heart;

    proc transpose data=&data(obs=0) out=names;
       var _all_;
       run;
    proc sql;
       select cats('_',_name_,'=missing(',_name_,');') into: stmts separated by ' ' from names;
       run;
    
    data missing;
       set &data;
       _BIGN = 1;
       /*%m_expand_varlist(data=&data,expr=cats('_',_name_,'=missing(',_name_,');'));*/
       &stmts;
       keep _:;
       run;
    proc summary data=missing;
       var _numeric_;
       output out=smry sum=;
       run;
    proc transpose data=smry(drop=_type_ _freq_) out=smry_;
       run;
    proc print width=minimum;
       run;
```

Then summarize these _: variables. Missing count will be SUM of 0/1

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort but what if I have 100 variables?  For example, you can see above in my code that proc summary gives me the missing values for all the numeric variables without me having to type the variables manually. I'm looking for some code which does something similar for character variables.

Comment: @saslearner I assumed you know about PROC SQL INTO I will update my answer.

Comment: @saslearner Adding _ to the name of existing variables assumes that no variable name is longer than 31 characters.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I need help in understanding your code. Perhaps you could answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74371361/could-someone-please-explain-what-the-following-lines-of-this-code-do/74371560#74371560